# Asymptotic counts for imaginary quadratic discriminants with fixed splitting conditions

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, asymptotics

Let $p$ be prime and $r$ be a positive integer. I am interested in asymptotics for the number of imaginary quadratic discriminants $d$ such that

1. $p$ does not divide the conductor of $d$,
2. $p$ splits in $\mathcal{O}_d$,
3. and the primes above $p$ have order dividing $r$ in the class group.

These discriminants can alternatively be described as the integers $\Delta := \frac{x^2 - 4p^r}{f^2}$, such that $x^2 - 4p^r < 0$, $x \not\equiv 0 \pmod{p}$, $\Delta \equiv 0, 1 \pmod{4}$, and $f^2$ is only required to divide $x^2 - 4p^r$.

I don't know much about asymptotics for these kinds of questions, so I'm not sure which of the two descriptions is more likely amenable to standard techniques. Does any one know of results in the literature for similar sets of discriminants, or where to find general tools that might be useful for approaching this problem?

Comment: Are you sure you mean "dividing $r$" and not "divisible by $r$" in 3.?

Comment: Yes, dividing $r$ is what I'm looking for